# Twisted.Web and AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, twisted

I've implemented a toy web service in Twisted.Web:

```
from twisted.web import server, resource, http

class RootResource(resource.Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
        self.putChild('test', TestHandler())

class TestHandler(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def __init__(self):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return self.render_POST(request)
    def render_POST(self, request):
        return "hello world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.listenTCP(8082, server.Site(RootResource()))
    reactor.run()
```

According to curl it works fine:

```
$ curl --url http://localhost:8082/test -v
[..]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 02 Aug 2010 11:54:35 GMT
< Content-Length: 13
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: TwistedWeb/8.2.0
< 
hello world!
```

Now, I'd like to call the service using the AJAX methods provided by JQuery. 
Here is the corresponding Java Script code:

```
[..]
// Submit button
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({type: "POST", 
            url: "http://localhost:8082/test",
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
              alert("Success:" + data);                  
            }
    });
});
[..]
```

Although the `success` callback gets called, `data` equals `null`. Does anybody have a clue why?

thanks, 
 Peter

Comment: Could it possibly be that your browser doesn't allow cross domain ajax stuff. What browser were you using?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the issue. I have used your server and your exact ajax call with JQuery and it loads fine. The alert box shows "Success: hello world!" as expected. You must have something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

dataType is important,if you use dataType: 'jsonp' you should send a callback from server side. i think because of this it works in curl and not work in your browser