# Ajax POST doesnt work / Twisted

Tags: javascript, ajax, twisted

[Twisted.Web and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387581/twisted-web-and-ajax)
Similar thread already exits . I even took code from there , yet i have the same problem , the twisted server works like a charm, but can't figure out why i can't fetch it with ajax.  In similar thread he says that alert comes out , but without data. For me even alert doesn't pop up , yet another ajax functions works , so in general with ajax is everything ok , but exactly with fetching something goes wrong.

As also said in similar thread  i can fetch it with curl - `$ curl --url http://localhost:8082/test -v` , and it shows hello world , so servers works fine 100 % .

Any ideas ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Submit button
$(function(){
  $.ajax({type: "POST", 
     $('a').click(function(){
        url: "http://localhost:8082/test",
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {alert("Success:" + data);}
    });
  });
});
</script>

<html>
[...]
  <a href="#">Load Favorites Movies</a>...
[...]
</html>
```

**server.py**

```
from twisted.web import server, resource, http

class RootResource(resource.Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
        self.putChild('test', TestHandler())

class TestHandler(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def __init__(self):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return self.render_POST(request)
    def render_POST(self, request):
        return "hello world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.listenTCP(8082, server.Site(RootResource()))
    reactor.run()
```

---

Big thank you to **Peter Le Bek** and **Darkporter**.
Peter Le Bek asnwer marked as correct  , and Darkporter vote up =) from me .

Answer :  Peter's answer works out of the box , just the thing that confused me a little bit was the line , where you had to specify the static folder. It is easy ... just sepcify any folder there , put there index.html and it will a root directory , when you access it on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your javascript is mangled, try this:

**wwwdir/index.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="#">click me</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('a').click(function(){
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8082/test",
            data: {},
            success: function(data) { alert("Success: " + data); }
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You'll probably still meet the [cross-domain HTTP request restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) mentioned by darkporter, to solve this serve your webpage using the same Twisted server:

**server.py**

```
from twisted.web import server, resource, http, static

class TestHandler(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def __init__(self):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return self.render_POST(request)
    def render_POST(self, request):
        return "hello world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    root = static.File('/path/to/wwwdir')
    testHandler = TestHandler()
    root.putChild('test', testHandler)
    reactor.listenTCP(8082, server.Site(root))
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: I'll come try your solution for sure. But i guess you both are right about 1 thing. I served page from another ip.  But even if i serve from the same server it still doesn't work , the way i did it. Well perhaps your example wirk work . I'll post later

Comment: You need to serve from the same IP _and_ port if you want browsers to accept it as same domain. Same IP alone isn't enough.

Comment: I did it . Thank you very much . You are right .Same port and ip is necessary. Of course it kind of brings me to another question how to use something like this lets say with django framework , which i serve from apache on 80 port . But thats i guess another story =)

Comment: In brief: either obviate same-origin policy by using [JSON-P](http://www.json-p.org/)/[CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), or serve Django and Twisted on the same port using [Apache's mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)/[Nginx's HttpProxyModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule)

Answer (score 4):

Is the page your JavaScript lives on served from the same host and port? If not you'll have a cross domain issue.

Comment: Nope. My server runs on lets say 192.168.0.196 on port 12345. But page is on my main computer 192.168.0.199 . And everything is behind the real ip lets say 24.124.41.23 . Port 12345 is forwarded to 192.168.0.196, so if i request  real ip 24.124.41.23:12345 i will see the page with ehllo world , which server serves .   Can you explain a little bit more about a cross domain issue ?

Comment: It's just a restriction that browsers all follow. If you load some HTML page, XMLHttpRequests (Ajax calls) in that page can only go to that some host and port, as seen from the browser's perspective. This is why making Ajax calls to `/ajax/whatever` is good, that will automatically go to the same host and port.

Comment: Why not just run everything from Twisted? That way you only have one thing to bind to port 80. If you're a Django fan, I've found the template engine Tempista to be quite nice, and it has Django template like syntax.