# AJAX Success Not Being Called on Twisted HTTP Return

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, twisted

I'm currently having trouble with communicating via AJAX on a Twisted HTTP Server in python. While I can send the request and have data accumulate on the server to be returned, when I try to return JSON back from the server through a simple return statement, it seems that it never calls the success function defined in Jquery AJAX, or at least its never triggered in firebug.

Snippet of Jquery Code: (Assume that its under document.ready):

```
function json_http_post(url, data, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    type: data.type,
                    source : data.source,
                    trade: data.trade,
                    symbols: data.symbols,
                    time1: data.time1,
                    time2: data.time2,
                    interval: data.interval
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

The twised sever implementation is similar (or near identical) to both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387581/twisted-web-and-ajax) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851998/ajax-post-doesnt-work-twisted).
The problem is that I never ever see callback(data) being called, yet I can see that python reaches my return statement with no errors and a json object to be sent back to the callback.

Comment: Are you sure the data type is `jsonp` and not `json`?

Comment: Check in firebug/chrome console and see what response is coming back. You may need to set your contentType to be text/json on both the AJAX call and your python endpoint.

Comment: hmm, so twisted is actually sending html back, an html string that represents a json object. How would I go about changing this??

Comment: If its sending a json string change the dataType to `json`

Comment: Already did. ;) I actually have the solution and will answer the question as soon as I can.